# Security of JBOD vs RAID while there is no backup

Tags: hard-drive, backup, security, raid, mdadm

I have some large amount of data (~40 TB) consisting of small files. The data is currently stored on JBOD. Because the data is not super important and I cannot afford the needed disks there is no backup. However, since it would not be nice to loose data because of a disk failure l am thinking about switching to RAID 6 (software raid mdadm).

Is it more secure to stay with JBOD or switching to RAID?

What happens if more than two disks fail?

Will all data be lost or is it possible to partially restore the data on the remaining disks?

Comment: I don't know what you mean... JBOD has no redundancy, if you lose a disk, the array fails.  RAID6 has redundancy where you can lose 2 disks.  The idea is, when a disk fails, you replace it, and keep your data.  With JBOD, you lose your data.

Comment: The data is currently stored completely indepent on serveral disks. If one disk fails the data on one disk will be lost. A RAID might be a solution. But what happens if more than two disks fail?

Comment: How many disks you have in your system? What's more important for you - disk space? Performance? Security? Or what combination of those? Anyway - in each scenario, if you won't replace faulty disks, sooner or later you'll lose your data. With JBOD - sooner. :) If you prefer to sacrifice some performance and security for the space - use RAID5 - but still you'll have to remember about replacing faulty disks. If you're happy to sacrifice a bit more of space and performance - you can go for RAID6 - it will give you "one more chance".

Comment: And on top of that - if the data is critical for you, backup is a good idea anyway. If you don't care about your data... well. No backup needed. But make sure it's really nothing that you might miss later. A lot of people redefine their meaning of importance of their data after losing their files in a disaster.

Comment: JBOD can be independent or spanned, if it's spanned (LVM), a disk failure causes the array to fail.  Independent, obviously the disks data is gone.  If more than 2 disks in RAID6 fails, you'll have difficulty rebuilding the array.  There aren't many scenarios where 3 disks would all fail at the same time.  Even then, if you had 3 disks fail in your JBOD, that seems unacceptable.  I work in the terms as, any data loss is unacceptable.  RAID6 gives you a chance to get the data back, JBOD does not.

Comment: The data is currently on ten 4TB disks. Loosing all data would be realy bad. In contrast loosing a small portion of it would not be nice but not armageddon since the dataset consists of several thousand independant files. Perfomance is realy not critical.